# read the output of a secret text file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the same credentials I need to inject in two different ways for different commands. As raw text and as a file path to a json file.

Im trying to do this but it does not work:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = credentials('myjsonkey')
GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS = "${new File( credentials('myjsonkey') ).text}"
```

Answer (score 5):

In a pipeline, the secret file have to be accessed like so

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'pets-id', variable: 'mySecretFile')]) {
    // some block can be a groovy block as well and the variable will be available to the groovy script
    sh '''
         echo "This is the directory of the secret file $mySecretFile"
         echo "This is the content of the file `cat $mySecretFile`"
       '''
}
```

'pets-id' is the id that i gave to the credential.

Comment: those are just shell commands, I want to store the raw text as an environment var (without having to run shell commands to manipulate it). Groovy should be able to read the file somehow

Comment: First you have to follow the dsl snippet syntax to retrieve the credential from jenkins. And then, you can have a groovy block inside the withCrendentials closure. It doesn’t mean only shell block works.

Comment: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = credentials('myjsonkey')` does the same thing

Comment: I doubt if there is a function call credentials(). Where did u get that from?

Comment: credentials() is the syntax to bind a specified credential to an environment variable in Declarative Pipeline syntax: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment